# Error al exportar bases de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo una base de datos con tablas que contienen emoticonos , pero a la hora de exportarlos e importarlos en un nuevo servidor, se me muestra algunos emoticonos pero hay otros sobre todo las del final que no me la muestra.

Me muestra un **?** en vez del emoticono. He intentado cambiar su utf8 a utf8mb4 antes de exportarlas pero no funciona.

Comment: El conjunto de caracteres se puede asignar a nivel columna, tabla, base de datos y sesión. Sin conocer cada valor de cada instancia de mysql/mariadb será adivinar por prueba y error.

Comment: Falta saber cómo está configurado el anterior y el nuevo. Y cómo estás validando el resultado, puede que tú conexión sea la que esté incorrecta

Answer (score 0):

Si es problema de la codificación, tienes que mantener la misma que tenías antes. Si no te deja utilizar la codificación que quieres (no se por qué motivo, no entiendo bien esa parte ya que tendrías que exportarla con el mismo formato que ya tiene), puedes crear la BBDD nueva con el formato que desees, e importar dentro de la misma sólo las tablas, no la BBDD completa.

Comment: He intentado importarlo localmente, y si que funciona. Pero en el nuevo servidor me aparece el ? en muchos emoticonos

Comment: Entonces problema del server, si con la misma codificación no te lo lee igual, aunque es bastante extraño. Eso ya sería buscar características propias del nuevo servidor en cuanto a la gestión de esos datos.